# Create a group variable first.treat indicating the first year each unit is treated

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following database:

```
ano    id_mun    tratado
1998    313240      0
1998    313250      0
1998    313260      1
 .        .         .
 .        .         .
 .        .         .
2019    317220      1
```

The data refers to PSF coverage from 1997 to 2019 and I want to identify the first year that the municipality received the program and started to be treated. Treated = 1, 0 otherwise. From this, I want to create the first.treat variable to estimate the diff-in-diff with multiple time periods.

I tried to create the first.treat variable through code:

```
df1 = amostra_final%>% 
  group_by(id_mun) %>% 
  mutate(first.treat = min(
    if_else(tratado == 1, ano, NA_integer_),
    na.rm = TRUE
  )) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

presented the following error;

```
Error in pre_process_did(yname = yname, tname = tname, idname = idname,  : 
  There is no available never-treated group
```

Comment: `mutate(first.treat = if_else(tratado == 1, min(ano, na.rm = TRUE), NA_integer_))`

Comment: `mutate(first.treat = min(ano[tratado == 1], na.rm = TRUE), .by = id_mun)`

Comment: the two codes did not work. I tried it this way: df = amostra_final %>% 
  group_by(id_mun) %>% 
  mutate(first.treat = min(ano[tratado == 1],na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
           ungroup()

Comment: and when I estimate att_gt it appears that:
Error in pre_process_did(yname = yname, tname = tname, idname = idname, :
  There is no available never-treated group

Answer (score 1):

```
df |> mutate(first_year_treated = ifelse(any(tratado == 1), min(ano[tratado == 1]), NA), .by = id_mun)
```

Output:

```
   ano id_mun tratado first_year_treated
1 1998 313240       0                 NA
2 1998 313250       0                 NA
3 1998 313260       1               1998
4 2019 317220       1               2019
```

Note: in the above example, half of the municipalities have no first year they were treated, so might give an error for the `pre_process_did()` function. Without seeing that function, or your actual data, you may have to filter out rows with NAs in first_year_treated, or just ones where every value in first_year_treated is NA.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly. I have this problem. I can share the data for you, I can't solve it. I need to create this pre-treatment to estimate diff-in-diff with multiple periods

Comment: perhaps you could include a larger sample dataframe, either using real data (gathered using dput) or fake data, which is similar, from which I can intuit the rules you want to follow in mutating the data